# PHP - How to select all users ever paid an order

Tags: orders, database, collection

I am working on a custom Magento Extension.

I am wondering how can i select all users who ever paid an order. I mean users which have one order with status `complete`.

Here is the code that has been given to me for this purpose, but it is not working as intended:

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $customers->joinTable(
            array('sales/order'),
            'customer_email=email',
            array('*'),
            null,
            'right'
        ); 


$data = $customers->getData();
foreach($data as $d)
{
    //print_r($d); // print this to see the available fields 
    echo $d[customer_email]; //get the desired information
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Right now i am wondering is it even possible ?

Comment: you don't seem to be testing the status of the order

Comment: I do not know how to test it. This code is suggestion given to me, but i think it is not even close.

Comment: how about you do it the other way around, query the orders which have been completed and join the user table with the emails?

Comment: Hmm.. sounds like it will do the job, but i don know how to make it.. :(

Comment: tony have check my answer

Answer (score 2):

First,you need to `decide how define  an order as paid`.

Basically, We have define `an order by order status.`

Order with status `Complete,invoice,Shipment,processing`calculated as paid order.

So,you need add `sales_flat_order table's column status to  your collection filler the collection`.

**EDIT:**

As you want to  filer customer collection by customer's   completed orders count that

I have

- Create a `sub Query` using  table `sales_flat_order table`

`$subSelect =  Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' )->getConnection( 'core_read' )->select()
            ->from(array('o' =>Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'COUNT(*)')
            ->where('o.customer_id = e.entity_id ');`

- `filter the table by status =complete`

`$subSelect->where('o.status = ?', 'complete');`

- Then add this `sub select query` to `customer collection` as  `new
  columns` (order_count) to customer collection.

`$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('order_count' => $subSelect))`

then using `having closure` filer by  this virtual columns :

```
`$collection->getSelect()->having('order_count > 0');`
```

**Try this query as you want on basic of complete orders**:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
$subSelect =  Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' )->getConnection( 'core_read' )->select()
            ->from(array('o' =>Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'COUNT(*)')
            ->where('o.customer_id = e.entity_id ')
            ->where('o.status = ?', 'complete');

 echo $collection->getSelect()->columns(array('order_count' => $subSelect))->having('order_count > 0');
-----
```

Comment: Yes i need orders with status `Complete` and then somehow i have to get information for all users, but i do not know how.\

Comment: wait i will give solution..